# How to make drop down field as mandatory field in views exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

I need to make one of my drop down field in views exposed filter as mandatory field.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Exposed Filter option check Required checkbox.. See attached screenshot below for select list field..

[image]